# Images are getting deleted from "camera shots" once sent in a text message

Tags: sms, htc-desire, photos

I have an HTC Desire Z,  Andorid 2.3.3 with HTC sense version 2.1.

If i take a photo and text it, that photo is getting deleted from my Gallery/camera shots.

How can I fix this so the photos are never deleted once taken without my permission?

**Edit**

I noticed some of my photos are still saved in the folder, but the gallery isn't displaying them, nor they accessible by the image applications. I can only see the pictures if I connect my sd card to my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With later updates to the system, it seems that the issue has resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that springs to me is to install Tasker (it is paid app, and quite cheap, but it is worth every cent).
Setup task that copies the last picture that was created into your SMS folder back to your DCIM (camera folder) folder.
 There are probably other solutions as well. If you cannot get the hang of Tasker, I will be more specific when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a .nomedia file in the folder. It could be what is causing the files to not display. A work around would be to install QuickPic for the Play store, it allows you to show hidden files on the device.

Comment: .nomedia file would affect all the images in the folder, not just the ones used in MMS.